# simple password cracker in scripting doesn't end when it find the correct password

Tags: shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

commonguess(){
for guess in $(cat passwordlist)
do
try=$(echo "$guess" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}' )
if [ "$try" == "$xxx" ]
then
echo "$name:$try"
break
fi
done
}
dict(){...}
brute(){...}

while IFS=':' read -r name hashing;do
commonguess
dict
brute
done
```

I have tested all 3 functions, they work fine. The only problem is in the bottom.

```
a:123
b:234
c:111
```

For example, i have this file named "user". If i run my code with this file, my code will test value of a(123) through 3 functions even it found answer in the first one. I don't want to do that, i want to do something like testing the value, if not found in function1 then move to next function, if it find answer then just move to next value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace break in commonguess for "return 0", add "return 1" to the end of the function, do the same for the other functions and change the while loop to:

```
while IFS=':' read -r name hashing;do
      commonguess || dict || brute
done
```

More information about the bash conditional short circuit evaluation here: 
http://wresch.github.io/2014/04/24/bash-short-circuit-evaluation.html

Comment: Thanks sir, it works!! By the way, do you know what is "declare -A" doing? I google it, i only found declare -i and declare -r.

Comment: declare -A is to make a bash associative array as explained here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays

use "help declare" or "help <bash-internal>" to check the help for bash internals.